# Which tags should be used for a questions about CCK fields?

Tags: discussion, tags

When a question is about CCK fields, should the question be tagged with [cck](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cck) and [fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields), or just with [cck](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cck)?

Should we consider [fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields) only for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CCK doesn't really exist for Drupal 7 my suggestion would be to use fields as a Drupal 7 tag only.

CCK also encompasses more than just fields in my opinion so my vote would be to keep them separate.

What would be cool is if you could only use fields with the drupal-7 tag and the same for cck and drupal-6.